# Mutliple Images in a Matrix row

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field that has a series of columns for showing content.

Each row has the following:

Title
Content
Image
Image Caption

Now sometimes I may want to have more than 1 image within each row, is there a way of doing that?

For example if I am writing content to talk about a project I am working on, and a section will be about Before and After shots.  The title will be something like Before and After, the content will be relevant to this, and I would want to have at least 2 images.  Other than adding cell is there a way of doing this?

Comment: have you checked out http://dvt.ee/nolan?

Comment: Yeah that looks like it would work well.

Comment: This is useful, but doesn't integrate with CE_Image.  Plus doesn't seem to grab the image manipulations I have setup with the file uploads.

Comment: You could use an Assets field in one Matrix column and allow multiple images for the Assets field. I would create a "before" and "after" column that have the Assets field type.